# How to connect to remote device without using any sotware

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, remote-access, remote-connection

**how can I access my pi using the static ip and I don't want to use any software or website for that**. Currently I am working on my ubuntu and I want to connect my raspberry pi over internet which is far away from me. Hope one of you might have answer to my question.
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: You have to use software. But it can be already installed or easily available on the system you are using. Since you are on Linux you likely have SSH or you can install it quickly. The real question is how the RPi is connected to the Internet. Is it directly exposed to the Internet or is it behind some router and in this case is there some NAT setup to allow you to pass through? Please answer by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. I have resolved this issue by creating a VPN server and created .ovpn file and placed it in client machine. For anyone who want to do the same, here's a documentation. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04